# Map Route with WCF Services

Tags: windows-phone-8, dictionary, routes, here-api

I have use WCF Services in an app.

I draw the line when going from 1 lists the coordinates returned from WCF. Then draw the wrong path. While Windows Phone 7 displays properly, using Polyline.

Shown below are the results that I got wrong:

[image]

And I want to display:

[image]

This is the code that I handle to draw:

```
void wcl_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result) || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Lỗi kết nối! Hãy thử lại");
            waitingPage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            return;
        }

        XuLyToaDo route = XuLyToaDo.TaoMapRoute();
        //Lay ds diem ve 
        string Ketqua = XuLyToaDo.DanhSachDiemVe(e.Result);
        string[] kq = Ketqua.Split('&');

        //Lay thong tin toa do 
        XuLyToaDo routePushpin = XuLyToaDo.TaoMapRoute();
        XuLyToaDo routePolyline = XuLyToaDo.TaoMapRoute();
        //MessageBox.Show(kq[0]);
        //MessageBox.Show(kq[1]);
        //MessageBox.Show(kq[2]);
        //Tao ds toa do 
        List<GeoCoordinate> lsToaDoPushpin = routePushpin.TaoDSToaDo(kq[0]);
        List<GeoCoordinate> lsToaDoRoute = routePushpin.TaoDSToaDo(kq[1]);
        // Lay ds ten duong 
        string[] MangTenDiaChi = routePushpin.TaoDSDuong(kq[2]);
        if (lsToaDoPushpin == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Không có thông tin");
            waitingPage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lsToaDoPushpin.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            AddRoute(lsToaDoPushpin[i], Colors.Blue);
        }
        //ve duong di
        for (int i = 0; i < lsToaDoPushpin.Count - 2; i++)
        {
            AddRouteMap(lsToaDoPushpin[i], lsToaDoPushpin[i + 1]);
        }
        //ve duong di
        //MyRouteQuery = new RouteQuery()
        //{
        //    TravelMode = TravelMode.Driving,
        //    Waypoints = lsToaDoRoute

        //};
        //MyRouteQuery.QueryCompleted += MyRouteQuery_QueryCompleted;
        //MyRouteQuery.QueryAsync();

        //Them danh sach tram
        int k = 0;
        foreach (GeoCoordinate geo in lsToaDoPushpin)
        {
            if (k == lsToaDoPushpin.Count() - 1)
                break;
            Pushpin pus = new Pushpin();
            string str = "Direc_" + k;
            pus.Template = Maps.App.Current.Resources[str] as ControlTemplate;
            pus.Tag = k;
            pus.Content = k.ToString() + ".   " + MangTenDiaChi[k];
            pus.Tap += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(pus_Tap);
            MyMap.Layers.Add(new MapLayer()
                {
                 new MapOverlay()
                 {
                    GeoCoordinate = geo,
                    PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5,0.5),
                    Content = pus
                }
               });
            k++;
        }
        MyMap.Center = lsToaDoPushpin[0];
        MyMap.ZoomLevel = 15;
        waitingPage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Lỗi kết nối. Hãy thử lại!!" + ex.Message);
    }
}

private void AddRouteMap(GeoCoordinate g1, GeoCoordinate g2)
{
    List<GeoCoordinate> lsRoute = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
    lsRoute.Add(g1);
    lsRoute.Add(g2);

    MyRouteQuery = new RouteQuery()
    {
        TravelMode = TravelMode.Walking,
        Waypoints = lsRoute

    };
    MyRouteQuery.QueryCompleted += MyRouteQuery_QueryCompleted;
    MyRouteQuery.QueryAsync();
}
void MyRouteQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e)
{

    if (e.Error == null)
    {

        if (MyMapRoute != null)
            AddlstMapRoute(MyMapRoute);
        MyRoute = e.Result;
        MyMapRoute = new MapRoute(MyRoute);
        MyMap.AddRoute(MyMapRoute);

    }
}
private void AddlstMapRoute(MapRoute maproute)
{
    lsMapRoute.Add(maproute);
}
private void AddRoute(GeoCoordinate geo, Color color)
{

    MyMap.Layers.Add(new MapLayer()
    {
        new MapOverlay()
        {
            GeoCoordinate = geo,
            PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5,0.5),

            Content = new Ellipse
            {
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color),
                Width =5,
                Height = 5
            }

        }
    });
}

void pus_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    Pushpin pus = sender as Pushpin;
    ToolTipService.SetToolTip(pus, new ToolTip()
    {
        DataContext = pus,
        Style = Application.Current.Resources["CustomInfoboxStyle"] as Style
    });
    MessageBox.Show(pus.Content.ToString(), "Thông tin trạm", MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
```

This is the place where I create database:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i guess its due to the fact that your travelmode is set to walking and google seems to think that walking there isnt allowed, so it takes the next possible way. try change the travelmode to driving or so.

greetings lars

Comment: No i get Properties travelmode = driving! Help me!